# Can't keep custom attributes in DOM?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, browser, viewstate

A very simple asp.net webform page.

```
<asp:DronDownList id="ddl" runat="server">
<asp:Button id="btn" runat="server" Text="Do nothing but post back" />
```

In Page_Load:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   ListItem item = new ListItem("text1","value1");
   item.Attributes["custom"] = "CustomValue";
   ddl.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The html it renders:(which looks good)

```
<select ...>
  <option value="value1" custom="CustomValue">text1</option>
</select>
```

After the button is clicked, I view the source, `custom="CustomValue"` is gone.
I know you will say "it's because you put it in a `if (!IsPostBack)` block". Of course everything will be ok if I remove the `if` statement. But why other STANDARD attributes are rendered? Since I put it in the `if` statement, i suppose the output will be:

```
<select ...></select>   // i suppose no options in it!
```

Why does ASP.NET "choose" attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a trade-off. Control has to persist (non-default)value of every attribute that it supports in the view-state. So there is naturally impact on the view-state size and hence page size. Therefore, it make sense for control developers only to back most commonly used attributes into the view-state. Same has been the case here - where control developers has decided not to back custom attributes into the view-state.

Comment: But how can I resolve this problem? I need the custom attribute.

Comment: Well you can add the attribute at design time. If the value may change then add the attribute every time page runs (i.e. in post-back scenario also). If you have to do it for many times then I will suggest that you write custom controls (inherited from say drop-down list) or user controls (containing say drop-down list), add code to persist custom attributes in view-state (overriding LoadViewState and SaveViewState methods).

Answer (score 0):

ASP .NET does not save custom attribute in ViewState.